# How to fetch the first row as object of class? (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

I borrowed the following wrapper class from [phpdelusions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper):

```
class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    public static function instance() {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function run($sql, $args = []) {
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

I've also set up a `users` table with `id`, `name`, and `password`. Now, I am trying to fetch the **first** row in the table as an **object** of class `User` (assume there is a `require_once 'User.php'` somewhere, which loads the model class):

```
$stmt = DB::run('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1');
$user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User'); // Array ( [0] => User Object ( ... ) )
```

It works, but

1. `fetchAll` always returns an array, and if the query above is somehow corrupted, the result might be a variable number of `User` objects, whereas the goal is to always get **one**, i.e. the **first** object, even if the query returns multiple rows.
2. Also, (2) despite `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_CLASS` in `instance()` method of `DB` which sets the default fetch style to CLASS, I always have to specify `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` in `fetchAll`, which I feel is redundant.
3. Lastly, to actually get the first row, I always need to check `$first = (is_array($user)) ? $user[0] : null;` since you never know if `$user` ends up to be empty or not. It would be easier to just fetch the first object and either get a legit row (`User` object) or just null. It doesn't make sense to get back an array, if your goal is to get **one** object, does it?

So I tried to change `fetchAll` to `fetch` with multiple variations, and here is what I got:

```
$user = $stmt->fetch('User'); // # 1, FETCH_MODE is already CLASS, but no...
// Warning:  PDOStatement::fetch() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given

$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User'); // # 2
// Warning: PDOStatement::fetch() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given

$user = $stmt->fetch(); // #3
//  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: No fetch class specified
// so how do you specify it then with fetch() ???
```

## Question

Is it possible to fetch the first row as an object of a given class using `fetch` alone? Or do I have no choice but write `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');` and then run `fetch`?

Comment: Also read about `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');` `fetch();`  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php Example3 ;)

Comment: Guys, the question is if its possible without `setFetchMode()` **and** `fetchAll()`.

Comment: No matter how many times I've seen people write PDO wrappers, I have yet to see a good one. Like this one, they always tend to be limited.

Comment: @Mikey This raises an interesting discussion. Why would you argue that this wrapper is limited? I can see that it only extends the functionality of PDO (`run()` any query safely) while allowing all its (static) methods (with `__callStatic`). Plus it guarantees one database connection for all queries

Comment: @Alex Wrapping something in is not really a good design. Effectively this causes 2 function calls with every interaction in PDO thus not efficient. You should read on extending PDO instead of wrapping it.

Comment: @Xorifelse I don't find much info about extending PDO, and tbh, I don't see a reason to. PDO seems powerful in itself, and the point of the wrapper above was to minimize code repetition (i.e. `run` instead of `prepare` + `execute`, but this could be further simplified; and once again I don't see a single PDO functionality that was _limited_). I do see that dependency injection is what you probably intended to suggest. Is it really safer and more robust than a singleton? There seems to be plenty of controversial opinions on this out there

Comment: @Mikey can you explain, why it is limited? In my opinion it is quite the opposite - the most flexible PDO wrapper ever possible, allowing you to utilize *every freaking single*  feature of PDO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well, for one thing, how would you connect to multiple databases at once as you are using a singleton pattern? Using constants to define the configurations prevents them from changing. Secondly, the beauty of PDO is that it allows me to connect to different drivers. Here I am only able to connect to MySQL drivers unless I change `$dsn` variable to use another constant e.g. `DB_DSN`.

Comment: @Mikey Ok, it's all about configuration. Clear. It's not a problem to add multiple databases support when needed. But I agree that your highbrow nitpicking is justified.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Highbrow nitpicking? You wrote a PDO wrapper to make it easier to use PDO. Well, if you are limited in how you make connections, then it isn't much help. Get off your high horse. If you can't accept criticism, don't ask for it.

Comment: @Mikey literally I agreed with you so you have nothing to complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only wanting 1 object, I can perfectly understand why you don't want to use `fetchAll()`. But since you want one, why not use [`fetchObject()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)?

As this is perfectly capable of being used in a while loop as well. Its like the `fetch()` for objects.

> Returns an instance of the required class with property names that correspond to the column names or FALSE on failure.

```
public mixed PDOStatement::fetchObject ([ string $class_name = "stdClass" [, array $ctor_args ]] )
```

Example:

```
class User{
  protected $data = [];

  public function __get(string $key){
    return $this->data[$key];
  }

  public function __set(string $key, $value){
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
  }

  public function __construct($a, $b, $c){
    echo $a, $b, $c;
    print_r($this->data);
  }
}

$stmt = DB::run('SELECT id, name FROM users LIMIT 1');

if($user = $stmt->fetchObject('User', [1, 2, 3])){
  echo $user->id;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that's precisely what I needed! Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I see, you are using my PDO wrapper. So you were in one click from the right answer, as there is a sister article [Fetching objects with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/objects#fetch) :)

So to make it with fetch(), you will need an extra function call

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

But, as it is rightfully said in the other answer, `fetchObject()` is better in either way:

```
$user = DB::run('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1')->fetchObject('User');
```